# VAO drawing wrong index

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am currently trying to draw shapes from a 3d engine that is already made for me that will output me a shape with vertices and triangles. the vertices are listed once only and triangles are built counterclockwise. I am having an Issue with the drawing part because at a certain point OpenGL starts using indices that I do not specify.

The code for setting up the shape into buffers and VBO is here:

```
//Reset index Count
    indicesCount.add(s.triangles().size() * 3);
    int vertexCount = s.getVertices().size() * 3;

    //Set Hash Map
    s.setHashMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertices().size(); i++) {
        System.err.println(s.getVertices().get(i));
    }

    //Initialize the Buffers
    vertBuff = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexCount);
    normalBuff = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexCount);
    indicesBuff = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indicesCount.get(this.objectCount - 1));

    //Place all the indices into the ByteBuffer
    ArrayList<Triangle> tempTriangles = s.triangles();

    for (Triangle t : tempTriangles) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            indicesBuff.put((s.getHashMap().get(t.vertex.get(i))));
            System.err.print(s.getHashMap().get(t.vertex.get(i)));
        }
        System.err.print('\n');
    }

    System.out.println("Hashmap: " + s.getHashMap().toString());

    //Place all the vertices in the FloatBuffer
    for (Vector v : s.getVertices()) {
        vertBuff.put((float) v.x);
        vertBuff.put((float) v.y);
        vertBuff.put((float) v.z);
        normalBuff.put((float) v.normalized().x);
        normalBuff.put((float) v.normalized().y);
        normalBuff.put((float) v.normalized().z);
    }

    //Close the Buffer for input
    vertBuff.flip();
    indicesBuff.flip();
    normalBuff.flip();

    generateOneVBO();
    setChanged(true);
}
 private void generateOneVBO() {

    vao_IDs.add(glGenVertexArrays());
    glBindVertexArray(vao_IDs.get(this.objectCount - 1));
    i_IDs.add(glGenBuffers());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_IDs.get(this.objectCount - 1));
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuff, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //Generate Buffers and get IDs
    v_IDs.add(glGenBuffers());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_IDs.get(this.objectCount - 1));
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuff, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

This is my render function(that loops whenever there is a change)

```
private synchronized void render(int p_Id) {
    Vector4f selectedColor = new Vector4f(1, 0, 0, 1f);
    Vector4f normalColor = new Vector4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);

    // glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
    for (int index = 0; index < v_IDs.size(); index++) {

        glBindVertexArray(vao_IDs.get(index));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        //  glPointSize(3.0f);
        // glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
        //Draw triangles
        if (selected.get(index)) {
            shader.setUniform(p_Id, "shapeColor", selectedColor);
        } else {
            shader.setUniform(p_Id, "shapeColor", normalColor);
        }
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount.get(index), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        //Draw Wireframe
        shader.setUniform(p_Id, "shapeColor", new Vector4f(1, 1, 1, 0.75f));
        //glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, indicesCount.get(index), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        int num = 0;
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        Vector4f[] arr = {
            new Vector4f(1f, 0, 0, 1),
            new Vector4f(0f, 1, 0, 1),
            new Vector4f(0f, 0, 1, 1)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < toDraw; i += 3) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                num++;
            }
            shader.setUniform(p_Id, "shapeColor", arr[num % 3]);
              glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, i + 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, i);
        }

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }
}
```

I made the render loop draw my triangle wireframe/triangles step by step by adding a click listener and adding 3 to the toDraw variable, with this i could see the first time it messes up.
In addition to the code i printed out both the hashmap that is used to convert from vertex to index, and an output of indices that is printed after each index is added to the buffer.

```
 Hashmap: {15.0 -15.0 15.0=2, -15.0 -15.0 15.0=3, 15.0 15.0 15.0=0, -15.0 15.0 15.0=1, -15.0 -15.0 -15.0=7, 15.0 -15.0 -15.0=6, -15.0 15.0 -15.0=5, 15.0 15.0 -15.0=4}
```

Indices:

```
201
213
315
357
045
051
264
240
675
654
623
637.
```

each triplet of numbers is a triangle so the first one is a triangle pointing at indices `2->0->1` and so on.

Here is the window after the first triangle[image: First Click(Good)]

Window after the second click
[image: Second Click(Good)]

Window after the third click which is where it first gets messed up
[image: Third click, as you can see it is pointing to vertex 0 instead of connecting back to 1]

I have been debugging this for a few days now and I do not know what is wrong. I think that it might be the way I draw it(the parameters I give it), but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not drawing triangles:

```
          glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, i + 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, i);
```

You are drawing Polygons with n vertices. For i=0, you will actually end up with a triangle. For `i=3` (and you're increasing `i` in steps of 3 in the loop`, you end up drawing an hexagon, with using 6 elements of your index buffer, starting from the fourth *byte*. And so on.

Comment: Hello, So ive fixed the problem and i had to multiply the offset by 4 to get it working like it should(with fixing the nth polygon problem). I understand why multiply by two because its unsigned int. but i dont get why 4 is needed because 2 didnt do the trick with the offset

Comment: The offset for `glDrawElements` is in _bytes_.  "I understand why multiply by two because its unsigned int" Uhm? A GLuint is defined to be 32 Bits, which is 4 bytes.